# Android adb shell dumpsys battery reset

Tags: adb, battery, dumpsys

What does this command do in Android headset?

```
adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

Do I need to do anything else after executing this command against a handset?

Answer (score 2):

`adb shell dumpsys battery` prints out `battery` service state. For testing purposes you might want to mock some battery state properties with `adb shell dumpsys battery set [property] [value]` command.

The `adb shell dumpsys battery reset` gets the device out of the simulation mode back to reporting actual state.